# Simulate html listbox dropdown on trigger over other action

Tags: events, drop-down-menu, listbox, simulate, dispatch

Please someone help me on the issue below.

I have a list dropdown box to be opened on trigger of a img div on top of it.

This works perfect in chrome, while it does not work in all other browsers like firefox, ie and others. I have a fiddle link ready which shows working example for chrome.

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/jNVwF/

Hope to hear from anyone of stack users.

## Gone through Reference - Similar stacks

[Firefox 5 dispatchEvent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474893/firefox-5-dispatchevent-not-working)
(Not working, Implemented)

What am i doing wrong with fiddle link?

Thanks again.
Sajay.