# JavaScript - dispatchEvent isn´t a function

Tags: javascript, dispatchevent, filesaver.js

My code:

```
// node = "<a href="blob:http%3A//..." download="export.csv"></a>"
var event = new MouseEvent("click");
node.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Console: `node.dispatchEvent is not a function`

The error only appears in Firefox (Chrome and IE works fine) 
Why isn´t the dispatchEvent firing?

Edit:
fileSaver.js-Code:

Chrome: `save_link=<a href="blob:http%3A//...efa07" download="export.csv"></a>`

Firefox: `save_link="<a href="blob:http%3A//...efa07" download="export.csv"></a>"`

```
click(save_link); 

click = function(node) {
  var event = new MouseEvent("click");
  node.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I think its a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474893/firefox-5-dispatchevent-not-working Check this link

Comment: Your `node` is incorrectly formatted. You need to escape your `"` marks or use `'` internally in the string.

Comment: now my node is:
`"<a href='blob:http%3A/...' download='export.csv'></a>"`

.. but it doesn´t work